# Access VBA: Number of query values and destination fields are not the same

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, append

I am trying to add data from an Access form to a table. When I ran sql code, I got an error message saying "number of query values and destination fields are not the same."

this is my code:

```
Private Sub CmdAddtoProductionDetails_Click() 
    Dim StrSql As String
    StrSql = "Insert Into test1 (ProductName, [Lot Number], ProductionDate, Quantity, Unit, Client) Values(me! ComboProduct1, me! LotNoProduct1, me! txtDate, me! Product1Quantity! me!ComboProduct1Unit, me! ComboProduct1Client)" 
    CurrentDb.Execute (StrSql) 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL string will be passed to the SQL engine which does not know how to interpret `me!ComboProduct1` etc. You need to insert the values of those variables into the string:

```
Private Sub CmdAddtoProductionDetails_Click() 
    Dim StrSql As String StrSql = "Insert Into test1 (ProductName, [Lot Number], ProductionDate, Quantity, Unit, Client)" & _ 
    " Values( '" & me! ComboProduct1 & "', '" & me! LotNoProduct1 & "', #" & Format(me! txtDate, "yyyy/mm/dd") & "#, " & CStr(me! Product1Quantity) & ", '" & me!ComboProduct1Unit & "', '" & me! ComboProduct1Client & "' )" 
    CurrentDb.Execute (StrSql) 
End Sub
```

Put single quotes around strings but not around numbers. Some of your fields I wasn't sure if they were numbers or strings - I made a guess.
You need to be careful with dates - check that the SQL engine is interpreting dates in yyyy/mm/dd format correctly. It will convert the string `#2016/06/04#` to a date automatically for you.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler and more direct method is to use a recordset:

```
Private Sub CmdAddtoProductionDetails_Click() 

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select Top 1 * From test1")
    rs.AddNew
        rs!ProductName.Value = Me!ComboProduct1.Value
        rs![Lot Number].Value = Me!LotNoProduct1.Value
        rs!ProductionDate.Value = Me!txtDate.Value
        rs!Quantity.Value = Me!Product1Quantity.Value
        rs!Unit.Value = Me!ComboProduct1Unit.Value
        rs!Client.Value = Me!ComboProduct1Client.Value
    rs.Update
    rs.Close

    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```