# Cause of "Run-time error code '3061' too few parameters. Expected 1."

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

The following code causes the error "Run-time error code '3061' too few parameters. Expected 1." but I'm not sure why:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
  'to add data to table
  CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO student(Name, Age, Sex, Email, Mobile, Course, Name_Of_Kin, Relationship, Email_Of_Kin, Mobile_Of_Kin, School_Fees, Qualification) " & _
  "VALUES (" & Me.txtName & " ,'" & Me.DTPAge & "','" & Me.cmbSex & "','" & Me.txtEmail & "','" & Me.txtMobile & "','" & Me.cmbCourse & "','" & Me.txtNOK & "','" & Me.cmbROK & "','" & Me.txtEOK & "','" & Me.txtMOK & "','" & Me.cmbFees & "','" & Me.cmbQual & "')"
  frmStudentSub.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: Name looks like a Text field but you are not surrounding txtName with single quotes in the query. All your other fields looks to be Text field as well according to your query. Make sure matching the field types and do the corresponding single-quote-surrounding correctly.

Comment: As a side note, MS-Access often gives you that kind of error whenever the SQL is viewed as invalid. It rarely gives you a detailed error pointing at the actual problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, have a look here:

[Insert record using a recordset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37628713/3527297)

Then, as it seems you insert the record in a table used by an open form, you can use the *RecordsetClone* of that form:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set rs = frmStudentSub.Form.RecordsetClone
    rs.AddNew
        rs!Name.Value = Me!txtName.Value
        rs!Age.Value = Me!DTPAge.Value
        rs!Sex.Value = Me!cmbSex.Value
        rs!Email.Value = Me!txtEmail.Value
        rs!Mobile.Value = Me!txtMobile.Value
        rs!Course.Value = Me!cmbCourse.Value
        rs!Name_Of_Kin.Value = Me!txtNOK.Value
        rs!Relationship.Value = Me!cmbROK.Value
        rs!Email_Of_Kin.Value = Me!txtEOK.Value
        rs!Mobile_Of_Kin.Value = Me!txtMOK.Value
        rs!School_Fees.Value = Me!cmbFees.Value
        rs!Qualification.Value = Me!cmbQual.Value
    rs.Update
    ' Not needed.    
    ' frmStudentSub.Form.Requery

    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for the feedback.